# Limit to using mariasql throwing error

Tags: node.js, mariadb, mariasql

I am using `mariasql` module in nodejs to connect with mariadb. 
My query is:

```
select * from products where id=1 order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

This query works fine when I pass fixed values to limit.

Now I tried taking values from parameters.

```
select * from products where id=:pid order by timestamp DESC LIMIT :start,:end
```

This query is throwing following error.

```
{ Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','10'' at line 1 code: 1064 }
```

where as it accepts value from parameter for where clause.

Comment: It would appear that the failure is caused by the fact that the parameters are converted to strings when they would need to be treated as numbers.

Comment: @markusjm, yeah it is converting parameters to string whereas it should be number but not for other parameters. Do you think it is issue with `mariasql` module?

Comment: You might first want to try something like the [`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function to see whether it helps.

Comment: @markusjm, parseInt won't work here as `mariasql` module internally converting parameter value to string.

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: @RickJames Latest version. The issue isn't with MariaDB but with `mariasql` node module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is issue in `mariasql` node module. The [issue](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/issues/166) is already reported in 2016 but there is no resolution yet.
Rather I found an alternative [module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) which is for `mysql` but works fine with `mariasql`.